# How can I pattern match on this?

Tags: pattern-matching, elixir, phoenix-framework

I have this expression:

```
obj1 = Repo.get_by(Struct1, var1: "123")
```

How can I pattern match on it so that it checks if a record exists and if its field "var2" is nil. Is it possible to do a pattern match
on that at all?

For now I'm doing this:

```
  cond obj1 do
    obj11  && (obj11.var2 == nil) -> #....
    true -> # doesn't exist or var2 isn't nil
  end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the pattern `%Struct1{var2: nil}`:

```
case Repo.get_by(Struct1, var1: "123") do
  %Struct1{var2: nil} -> #...
  _ -> #...
end
```

Comment: can I bind "%Struct1{var2: nil}" to a variable? Something like `my_var@%Struct1{var2: nil}` without having to create a variable before a pattern matching?

Comment: @darko, yes: `my_var = %Struct1{var2: nil} -> #...`.

Comment: if Struct1 has multiple fields, should I use `_`  in  `%Struct1{_, var2: nil}` or not neccesary?

Comment: @darko you don't need as a map pattern ignores extra fields on the matching value (`%{a: 1}` matches `%{a: 1, b: 2}`). Also that code does not compile and there's no syntax for explicitly ignoring fields precisely because it's not required.